# redis json (redislabs/rejson:latest) on Heroku

Tags: docker, heroku, redis

I cannot figure this out. Hope I can get some help

I have a hobby tier in Heroku running django. To this I would like to attach a Redis service. However, I would like to use the recent rejson (redislabs/rejson:latest) docker image (instead of redistogo or heroku-redis)because it has json support. This works great on my local env. I was able to push the docker image into the container registry and actually start the redis server

```
2021-07-23T00:14:48.576294+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3:M 23 Jul 2021 00:14:48.576 # Current maximum open files is 10000. maxclients has been reduced to 9968 to compensate for low ulimit. If you need higher maxclients increase 'ulimit -n'.
2021-07-23T00:14:48.577054+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3:M 23 Jul 2021 00:14:48.577 * Running mode=standalone, port=6379.
2021-07-23T00:14:48.577124+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3:M 23 Jul 2021 00:14:48.577 # Server initialized
2021-07-23T00:14:48.577184+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3:M 23 Jul 2021 00:14:48.577 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory = 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
2021-07-23T00:14:48.577671+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3:M 23 Jul 2021 00:14:48.577 # <ReJSON> JSON data type for Redis v1.0.7 [encver 0]
2021-07-23T00:14:48.577789+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3:M 23 Jul 2021 00:14:48.577 * Module 'ReJSON' loaded from /usr/lib/redis/modules/rejson.so
2021-07-23T00:14:48.578232+00:00 app[worker.1]: 3:M 23 Jul 2021 00:14:48.578 * Ready to accept connections
```

Unfortunately, django is unable to connect to it

```
ConnectionError: Error -2 connecting to redis://localhost:6379. Name or service not known
```

- There are no ENV variable exposed, so am unable to set any (I mean I can set them, but doubt if they will be relevant)
- I did experiment with installing redistogo add on and am able to connect to it (this required setting the connection based on the REDIS_URL env variable that gets exposed when redistogo is added)

At my wits end...any help appreciated...I guess the question really boils do to:

Comment: I think the reason is `redis://localhost:6379.` need to be corrected. I don't think it will be localhost.

Comment: no it won't be localhost...the question really is "what is the endpoint ?"...as I mentioned, unlike with their redis addon, there is no environment variable available/set when I deploy rejson

Comment: Did you consider to just use the managed RedisJSON? See:  https://elements.heroku.com/addons/rediscloud

Comment: @GuyKorland yes, that's what it seems like I need to end up doing. Even there, it's a bit weird. documentation says that it comes default with json (ie, rejson module), but that doesn't seem to be the case...it's able to connect, but doesn't recognize json set/gets. am also trying it with a password option back on heroku to see if that's what's causing it to not work.

Comment: Managed to get this working by using Redis enterprise cloud. The addon from Heroku (for Redis enterprise cloud) wont work for this. The reason is that it doesn't allow one to load the rejson module. The module needs to be loaded via the Redis cloud dashboard. However, when added on from Heroku, the linked Redis dashboard doesn't show the option to load the module. Thus the way was to create the Redis cloud deployment independently and use the credentials on the Heroku side within the app runtime

Comment: This is super duper wierd. Straighway goes exactly opposite to their documentation :(